# Azure backup conflict with SQL database backup chain

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Our SQL VMs in Azure are currently being backed up via Azure backups on a daily basis. We have noticed however that this is affecting our differential backup chains - how do we create a regular server snapshot backup image of the SQL server without affecting the SQL database backup chains on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Azure Backup service uses VSS snapshot backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-introduction), which means it's going to quiesce SQL Server. The good news is that you get good backups (as opposed to crash-consistent ones), but of course the bad news is that they're not copy-only backups.

What you're probably looking for is crash-consistent backups (dirty snapshots) - search for "crash" on that Azure Backup documentation link. To get that in Azure, you'd need to lose the Azure VM agent, which comes with different drawbacks. (On-premises, this is easier since you can just tell your hypervisor to grab a dirty snapshot backup without engaging VSS.)